# Get all users from the database

Tags: java, mysql

So im making a project and i need to add some users. In my case postman return only one user. I am kinda new to java and i am working only on this thing for a week now. Someone pls help.

```
public List<User> getAll() {

    try {
        Connection connection = DBConnect.getNextConnection();
        NamedParameterStatement statement = new NamedParameterStatement(connection, getAll);

        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

        while (resultSet.next()) {

            User user = new User();
            user.setId(resultSet.getString("id"));
            user.setEmri(resultSet.getString("name"));
            user.setMbiemri(resultSet.getString("surname"));
            user.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email"));
            user.setMosha(resultSet.getInt("age"));

            userList.add(user);
            return userList;
        }
        resultSet.close();
        statement.close();
        connection.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Is the `return` inside your loop the problem? Shouldn't that be outside the loop?

Comment: If its outside the loop. What will the loop do?

Comment: "What will the loop do?" => create user objects and add them to the list? (and it looks like `userList` is initialized outside the method; it should probably be method-local and declared directly before the loop.

Comment: `return` is your way of saying "We're done here, wrap it up!" and you're doing that after the first record is processed. You need to move that outside the loop, and Aleksa has provided a good answer that explains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) has pointed out in your comments, the return statement needs to be outside of your loop, something like:

```
public List<User> getAll() {
    try {
        Connection connection = DBConnect.getNextConnection();
        NamedParameterStatement statement = new NamedParameterStatement(connection, getAll);

        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

        while (resultSet.next()) {

            User user = new User();
            
            user.setId(resultSet.getString("id"));
            user.setEmri(resultSet.getString("name"));
            user.setMbiemri(resultSet.getString("surname"));
            user.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email"));
            user.setMosha(resultSet.getInt("age"));

            userList.add(user);
        }
        
        resultSet.close();
        statement.close();
        connection.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    
    return userList;
}
```

Comment: But now it returns only one user twice

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns only one user twice"? Method getAll() returns a List with two identical users?

Comment: Yeah it return the same user twice

Comment: Without having an access to you whole project and source code it is difficult to say what the exact problem is. My guess is that there is a problem with your SQL query or with data stored in your database. What is a value of variable 'getAll' used in line "NamedParameterStatement statement = new NamedParameterStatement(connection, getAll);"?

Comment: The problem was that User user = new User(); was outside of the loop, and i just put it inside. Thanks Anyway...